# laravel 4 output json order desc

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-4, sql-order-by

I use laravel 4.2
How can I output json in desc order? Thanks.

Below is my code :

```
public function show($id) {
    $member = $this->getMember ();
    $transition = $member->getTransition ( $id )->first ();
    $transition_info = $transition-> transitionInfo;
    return ResponseWrapper::toJson ( $transition_info );
}
```

...

```
public function index() {
    $member = $this->getMember ();
    $transitions = $member->getTransitions ();

    return ResponseWrapper::toJson ( $transitions );
}
```

/* 12/28 update */

Maybe I should change in below model?
 (project/app/models/Member.php)

```
public function getTransitions() 

{
$array = $this->hasMany('Transition', 'payeer_id', 'id')->select($this->transition_index_payeer_column)->get()->all();

$arrayb = $this->hasMany('Transition', 'remitter_id', 'id')->select($this->transition_index_remitter_column)->whereRaw('NOT (card_type_remitter = "focas" and focas_status = "")')->get()->all();

$reuslt = array_merge ( $array, $arrayb );
return $reuslt;
}
```

Comment: plz ad the output of $transitions

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function index() {

    $member = $this->getMember ();
    $transitions = $member->orderBy('id','desc')->getTransitions ();

    return ResponseWrapper::toJson ( $transitions );

}
```

Comment: Thks. But it's not working.No matter  1 or 2


1.  $transitions = $member->orderBy('id','desc')->getTransitions ();
2.  $transitions = $member->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->getTransitions ();

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
public function index() {

    $member = $this->getMember ();
    $transitions = $member->getTransitions()->orderBy('id','desc')->get();

    return ResponseWrapper::toJson ( $transitions );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Laravel V4 :**

```
 $transitions = $member::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->getTransitions();
```

Comment: also try to replace `->getTransitions();`  with `->get();` only

Comment: (1)Error msg is : 
12-27 17:31:42.325 5258-5320/com.xxx E/FruitCoin: createResponse():70: org.json.JSONException: No value for message
    createResponse():70: org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
    createResponse():70: org.json.JSONObject.getInt(JSONObject.java:478)
    createResponse():70: com.xxx.rest.Response.createResponse(Response.java:60)
12-27 17:31:42.335 5258-5320/com.xxx E/FruitCoin: createResponse():70: com.xxx.rest.HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(HttpTaskFactory.java:110)
    createResponse():70: com.xxx.rest.HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(HttpTaskFactory.java:69)

Comment: createResponse():70: android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    createResponse():70: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    createResponse():70: android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    createResponse():70: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    createResponse():70: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    createResponse():70: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: 12-27 17:31:42.365 5258-5258/tw.com.now D/InputMethodManager: windowDismissed mLockisused = false
12-27 17:31:42.405 5258-5258/com.xxx D/InputMethodManager: windowDismissed mLockisused = false
12-27 17:31:42.405 5258-5258/com.xxx E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: (2)12-27 17:39:48.659 5914-5914/com.x E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
12-27 17:39:49.090 5914-5962/com.x E/SQLiteLog: (2067) abort at 21 in [INSERT OR FAIL  INTO cards(m_publisher_name,m_encoded_card_number,m_balance,id,m_exp_year,m_sub_type,m_exp_month,m_type) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: cards.id
12-27 17:39:49.110 5914-5962/com.x E/SQLiteLog: (2067) abort at 21 in [INSERT OR FAIL  INTO cards(m_publisher_name,m_encoded_card_number,m_balance,id,m_exp_year,m_sub_type,m_exp_month,m_type) VALUES (?,?...)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: cards.id
...